# Is there a way to install extension for XamarinStudio (MonoDevelop) silently?

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin-studio

Visual studio has VSIXInstaller that can install extension silently. Does Xamarin Studio has same feature??

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
mdtool setup i PATH_TO_MPACK
```